# How to find and delete folder in windows 7 using commandline

Tags: windows, command-line

In my C directory 3 folders are there named as DIR1 DIR2 DIR3 each folder contains folder Z.
I want find all the Z folders. And I want to delete them. Is it possible? I dont no anything about windows.

I tried this command it's only listing, but how to delete.

`dir c:\Z /s /d`

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will remove all `Z` subdirectories keeping `DIR1` `DIR2` and `DIR3`:

```
for /D %d in (C:\DIR\*) do rmdir /S /Q %d\Z
```

See also:

```
for /?

rmdir /?
```

Comment: The above solution is working fine for me, now just imagine if there is a space in between "DI R" at that time what modification are needed in above command to avoid a space?

Comment: Enclose the paths in quotes: `for /D %d in ("C:\DIR\*") do rmdir /S /Q "%d\Z"`

Comment: Now the folder structure is changed, structure is like this `"A S"->A->B-C->20130113-Z` Here "A S" is the main folder, and I want to delete Z.

Comment: `for /R "C:\A S" /D %d in (*) do @if "%~nd" == "Z" echo "%d"` (replace `echo` with `rmdir /S /Q`) after testing.